# Probability density function of $Z = X \sin Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The probability density function of a random variable $X$ is a uniform distribution $U(a,b)$. Likewise, the probability density function of a random variable $Y$ is a uniform distribution $U(0, 2\pi)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent of each other.

What is the probability density function of $Z = X \: \sin{Y}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1: $(0 < a < b)$**
To proceed, let $X$ have pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

where I am initially assuming parameter $a$ is positive. I will consider the alternative cases later. Second, let $W = sin(Y)$ with pdf $\phi(w)$:

[image]

The latter is relatively straightforwards to derive.

Next, we seek the pdf of the product of two random variables, namely $Z = X * W$. This can be cumbersome to do by hand, but can be derived easily using the `TransformProduct` function in the `mathStatica` suite. In particular, the pdf of $Z$, say $g(z)$ is:

[image]

All done. (I should add I am one of the authors of the software.)

Here is a plot of the theoretical pdf derived $g(z)$ (in red) when $a = 2$ and $b = 5$, and superimposed on top a Monte Carlo check (in blue).

[image]

---

The other 2 cases (with parameter $a< 0$) are derived in identical fashion ... just change the assumptions on parameters $a$ and $b$ in the first input. Doing so yields:

**Case 2: $(a < 0, b > 0)$**

The solution pdf is $g(z)$:

[image]

Here is  a plot of the solution pdf $g(z)$ when $a = -3, b = 2$:

[image]

**Case 3: $(a < b < 0)$**

The solution pdf is $g(z)$:

[image]

Here is  a plot of the solution pdf $g(z)$ when $a = -4, b = -2$:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Recall that a general procedure to compute the distribution of $Z=X\sin Y$ when $(X,Y)$ are independent with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ is to compute $E[u(Z)]$ for every bounded measurable function $u$. If it happens that
$$
E[u(Z)]=\int_\mathbb Ru(z)g(z)\mathrm dz,
$$
then $g$ is the density of $Z$. Here,
$$
E[u(Z)]=\iint u(x\sin y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
hence the job is to transform this double integral into the simple integral above. The way to do that is rather clear: change of variables.

Consider $(z,t)=(x\sin y,x\cos y)$ and assume for example that $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Y$ uniform on $(0,2\pi)$, then $\mathrm dz\mathrm dt=x\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ and $x^2=z^2+t^2$ hence
$$
E[u(Z)]=\iint_{z^2+t^2\leqslant1} u(z)\frac{\mathrm dz\mathrm dt}{2\pi\sqrt{t^2+z^2}},
$$
and one sees that
$$
g(z)=\mathbf 1_{|z|\leqslant1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{2\pi\sqrt{t^2+z^2}}=\frac1\pi\mathbf 1_{|z|\leqslant1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}/z}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}},
$$
that is,
$$
g(z)=\frac1\pi\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac1z\right)\mathbf 1_{|z|\leqslant1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but I prefer the one of @wolfies because it is more complete.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist No problem (and thanks for the accompanying comment). Are you able to derive the formulas stated in the accepted post?

Comment: You are right, this is a big plus of your answer. Maybe I'm more prone to accept the @wolfies answer because as a physicist I've difficulties to understand your answer. It's a pity that I can't choose both.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist Difficulties to understand an answer are a parameter you had not mentioned yet. Sorry to hear that. You might want to expand on said "difficulties" (that is, if the learning process of overcoming them interests you--by contrast with, say, simply getting an answer).

Comment: @wolfies: You might want to remove your comment since it does not apply at all. To Did: +1 for the "let us calculate ${\rm E}[u(Z)]$ for bounded measurable $u$" approach.

Comment: @Did When I first read your answer, I missed your assumption that $a=0$ and $b=1$, in part because it is not assumed in the question, giving rise to your special simple domain of support $(-1,1)$ in your solution. Is there a reason you have assumed $a = 0$ and $b =1$, or is it possible to solve the problem using your method for general $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @wolfies The method is hardly "mine". Of course it is "possible" to use it when (a,b) is not (0,1)... As my post explicitely states, the method is universal, which is the reason why it is taught in countless probability courses.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that c. d. f. of $Z$ is $$P\{Z<z\}=P\{X\sin Y<z\}=\iint\limits_{x\sin y<z} p_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\int\limits_{-\infty}^{z/x}p_{XY}(x,y)dy=\\=\int\limits_a^{b}dx\int\limits_{0}^{z/x}p_{XY}(x,y)dy$$

The probability density function will then be $$\frac{d}{dz}\left(\int\limits_a^{b}dx\int\limits_{0}^{z/x}p_{XY}(x,y)dy\right)$$